# GUI for NFTables, like fwbuilder

Tags: iptables, gui

We have several clients where we use linux based (iptable) firewalls.
To manage the rulesets we currently use [fwbuilder](http://www.fwbuilder.org/) to manage the firewalls and the relations between the different firewalls.

So far we have been happy with it.

But it does not support NFTables natively and also the active development of fwbuilder seems to have stopped arround 2011-2013.

What other options have we for a GUI centric solution to manage script for multiple firewalls? (Like fwbuilder or checkpoint has)

Comment: Do you want this to run on a vanilla NetFilter installation or are you looking for a dedicated NetFilter (iptables) based firewall? I know several products that are NetFilter based but packaged as a GUI Firewall distro.

Comment: I look for a central way to manage/build fw rules for multiple (related/grouped) firewalls. On what platform this runs isn't relevant to us.

Comment: Try adding this requirement/issue onto the GitHub page for fwbuilder ?  https://github.com/UNINETT/fwbuilder

Comment: Do you mean the project on GitHub is still alive?

Answer (score 2):

The development of fwbuilder is active again since some months.

The current repository can be found on github and patches are accepted.

https://github.com/fwbuilder/fwbuilder

Answer (score 0):

you can also try a SAAS solution for managing iptables -> https://www.efw.io/Forum it can do AWS cloud integration if needed.

Comment: "/Forum" does not work, it redirects to "/".

Comment: was referring to their product.

Comment: I think he said notables, not iptables.

Answer (score 0):

[**nftables-gui**](https://github.com/caballeroalba/nftables-gui) is a [TUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based%5Fuser%5Finterface)/[CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line%5Finterface) based (wrapper) tool to configure [nftables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nftables)(nft) in Ubuntu-GNU/Linux, (Ubuntu is a derivative of Debian). Source-code can be compiled in GNU/Linux when it has ncurses, nftables, & Linux-kernel 3.13 or above.
nftables-gui uses [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) based TUI (GUI-like) interface to be used from CLI shell/terminal window of a [GUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical%5Fuser%5Finterface)-based or GUI-less GNU/Linux.
instruction is in Spanish language.
it was released 5yrs ago, for Linux kernel 3.13.

I just made a github fork [here](https://github.com/atErik/nftables-gui/)([english](https://github.com/atErik/nftables-gui/tree/nftables-gui_mod-english)) & intend to improve it & provide English translation, Still working on it, and any help is appreciated.

Comment: `nftables-gui` last commit is 6 years ago...

Answer (score 0):

As of 2021 fwbuilder is "active" however they do not seem to have any plans or goals to implement support for nftables. Furthermore, there hasn't been any commits in the past 11 months and a release candidate for 6.0.0 has not been acted upon during that time either. It seems the new owners of the project believe "iptables still works fine" despite iptables being deprecated and modern distributions now using nftables by default. Forum inquiries about nftables are met with "why don't you implement the nftables compiler for us." Which is valid but shows that the owners have not identified this feature as a needed priority.